# Kinect depth data is saturated to 1 meter

Tags: ros, kinect, ros-groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everybody,

I'm using the simulated kinect of gazebo with the `gazebo_ros_openni_kinect` plugin. It works fine when the kinect is looking at objects that are closer than 1 meter, but when the objects are at a distance bigger than 1 meter the depth value is always 1. It is not depending on the near/far clip set in the urdf of the kinect. I'm using ros groovy and gazebo 1.9, the image is taken from the topic `/depth/image_raw`, but even rviz shows a semi-flat point cloud (that is, flat when the depth is bigger than 1 meter).

Does anyone know how to fix that problem? Thanks!

EDIT:
the rgb image works correctly.

depth/image_raw:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xlycy5troq7g4v0/depth.jpg

rgb/image_raw:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/y0am9uxv7ivub6b/rgb.jpg

This is how the kinect sensor is defined in the urdf:

```
  <!-- xtion sensor -->
  <gazebo reference="xtion_link">
    <sensor type="depth" name="xtion_sensor">
      <update_rate>20.0</update_rate>
      <camera>
        <horizontal_fov>1.047</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>640</width>
          <height>480</height>
          <format>R8G8B8</format>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.05</near>
          <far>3</far>
        </clip>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <!-- Noise is sampled independently per pixel on each frame.  
               That pixel's noise value is added to each of its color
               channels, which at that point lie in the range [0,1]. -->
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.001</stddev>
        </noise>
      </camera>
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <plugin name="Xtion_frame_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so">
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>20.0</updateRate>
        <cameraName>xtion</cameraName>
        <imageTopicName>ir/image_raw</imageTopicName>
        <cameraInfoTopicName>ir/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
        <depthImageTopicName>depth/image_raw</depthImageTopicName>
        <depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>depth/camera_info</depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>
        <pointCloudTopicName>depth/points</pointCloudTopicName>
        <frameName>xtion_depth_optical_frame</frameName>
        <pointCloudCutoff>0.05</pointCloudCutoff>
        <distortionK1>0.00000001</distortionK1>
        <distortionK2>0.00000001</distortionK2>
        <distortionK3>0.00000001</distortionK3>
        <distortionT1>0.00000001</distortionT1>
        <distortionT2>0.00000001</distortionT2>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>

  <!-- xtion rgb camera -->
  <gazebo reference="xtion_link">
    <sensor type="camera" name="xtion_rgb_camera">
      <update_rate>20.0</update_rate>
      <camera>
        <horizontal_fov>1.047</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>640</width>
          <height>480</height>
          <format>R8G8B8</format>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.05</near>
          <far>3</far>
        </clip>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <!-- Noise is sampled independently per pixel on each frame.  
               That pixel's noise value is added to each of its color
               channels, which at that point lie in the range [0,1]. -->
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.001</stddev>
        </noise>
      </camera>
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <plugin name="Xtion_rgb_camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>20.0</updateRate>
        <cameraName>xtion</cameraName>
        <imageTopicName>rgb/image_raw</imageTopicName>
        <cameraInfoTopicName>rgb/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
        <frameName>xtion_rgb_optical_frame</frameName>
        <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
        <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
        <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
        <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
        <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
        <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4304/kinect-depth-data-is-saturated-to-1-meter/) by [Tirjen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/489/tirjen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am running Gazebo 1.9 with ROS Hydro and everything seems to work correctly. I did have to install the gazebo_plugins from source since there was a bug in the gazebo_ros_openni plugin (which has since been fixed).

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/489/tirjen/) on 2013-09-18**:
I installed ROS Hydro and now it works correctly, thanks!